# Create xml file from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xmldom

Found this script what nearly does what I want; But not all the way.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;

$table = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('incidents'));

foreach($result as $row) {
$data = $dom->createElement('incident');
$table->appendChild($data);

foreach($row as $name => $value) {

    $col = $dom->createElement('column', $value);
    $data->appendChild($col);
    $colattribute = $dom->createAttribute('name');

    $colattribute->value = $name;
    $col->appendChild($colattribute);
```

It now gives an xml result with:

```
<column name="id"> and </column>
```

I would like this to be

```
<id> and </id>
```

What do I have to changed? I've tried all the options I can think of.

This is only the middle part. The rest seems to work fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [function `createElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) does exactly this - creates new element.
The first parameter will be the name of your element (in your case - **column**):

```
$col = $dom->createElement('column', $value);
```

If you want to have an element with the name `id` you should use the `id` as the name of the element:

```
$col = $dom->createElement('id', $value);
```

### Update - a better explanation:

The function `createElement` gets 2 parameters. The first parameter is the name of the tag, the second parameter is the content of the tag.
This mean that if you do:

```
$col = $dom->createElement('ThisIsMySpecialTagName', 'ValueValueValue');
```

You will get

```
<ThisIsMySpecialTagName>ValueValueValue</ThisIsMySpecialTagName>
```

You can put in the **first** parameter whatever you want the name of the tag (the thing that comes between `<` and `>`) and the **second** parameter is the content of the tag (what comes between the opening and the closing tag).

Comment: Then it gives me: 
`<id name="id"> and </id>` 
What i'm looking for is just `<id> and </id>`
without the `id name=` part

Comment: It can also be <time> and </time> etc. 
I would like to have the $value as tag by itself.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the problem. How do you choose the name of the tag?

Comment: The name is chosen as column in a Mysql db. What I'm trying is to get the $value between as <$value> in stead of the $value as '<id name='$value'>

Comment: So you can use `$col = $dom->createElement($value, $value);`

Comment: "Doesn't work" what exactly? I still can't understand what you are looking for, so obviously it's hard to give a solution. I'm not sure you know what you are looking for :)

Comment: I want the xml output to be like <id>001</id>. The document now gives <column name='id'>001</column>. That is really different. ;-)

Comment: where did the "id" come from? And why now it's "id"? before it was "time"? what cause the change?

Comment: The 'id' 'time' or other value is the $value that comes as column name in the mysql database.

Comment: So you have the name of the tag in the variable `$name` and you want the content of the tag to be what you have in the variable `$value`. Right?

Comment: I want an xml like this;

Comment: Sorry, can't make the list on the phone <incidents><incident><id>1</id><time>13:00</time><location>blabla</location></incident><incident><id>2</id><time> etc... etc... Ending with </incident></incidents>.

Comment: Read again my question and answer accordingly. Don't explain the final output you want. Explain the way to get it.

Comment: The <incidents><incident> works fine. But after that it does everything in <column name='#'>

Comment: And again - read **everything** I wrote. Do you understand how the `createElement` function works? What is the first parameter and what is the second?

Comment: Read the update in my answer. I don't want to give the the exact solution, because I really don't think you will learn anything this way.

Comment: It works, I took out the three lines that make the colattribute.